# Showing $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^4$ do not have the same Stiefel-Whitney numbers.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^4$ do not have the same Stiefel-Whitney numbers.

I have a theorem that says "If $n+1$ is not a power of 2, then $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is not a boundary of a compact manifold. Since 5 is not a power of 2, then $\mathbb{R}P^4$ is not a boundary of a compact manifold.

I also have a theorem that says "If a closed manifold is a boundary of a compact manifold, then all its Stiefel-Whitney numbers are 0."

I can't use this, correct? It's not the right logic to use the fact I have with this theorem?

I'm ultimately trying to prove that  $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^2$ is not cobordant to $\mathbb{R}P^4$. Please help me find a way to prove this!

Comment: Do you know the formula $w_k(M \times N) = \sum_{i+j=k} w_i(M) \times w_j(N)$?

Answer (score 1):

The SW class of $\mathbb{RP}^4$ equals
$$
(1+a)^{4+1}=1+a+a^4.
$$
From this it is seen that $\langle w_1^4(\mathbb{RP}^4),[\mathbb{RP^4}]\rangle=1$ and $\langle w_4(\mathbb{RP}^4),[\mathbb{RP^4}]\rangle=1$ and all other numbers vanish.

For $\mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ we get that the stiefel whitney class is
$$
(1+a)^3(1+b)^3=1+a+b+a^2+ab+b^2+a^2b+ab^2+a^2b^2
$$
and for example $w_1^4(\mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2)=0$ so the associated Stiefel-Whitney number also vanishes.

The first Stiefel-Whitney number of $\mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2+\mathbb{RP}^4$ does not vanish, hence this manifold is not nullbordant. Thus $\mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ is not cobordant to $\mathbb{RP}^4$.